# Better code reuse

Tags: vb.net, dataset, oledb

I am making a program in VB.Net that connects to a database and allows users to add, edit, and delete records etc. I however want to be able to use a module to create Sub Routines and Functions and referencing them in my forms. I have found a way to get the field names of the table in the dataset so that i can use a loop to get the field and write data to it. My problem however is that the controls used to write to these fields have to be explicitly named  (e.g. txtFirst_Name or cboSubjects). That makes it difficult for me to achieve my tasks as I wont be able to use a loop to add to the fields and i would have to write a line for every input field on a form instead of looping through 10 times for example. Below are copies of my code including use of subs.

Adding to database

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    query = "Select * from Supplier"
    getTable()
    Try
        Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dSet_NewRow As DataRow
        dSet_NewRow = dSet.Tables("Table").NewRow
        dSet_NewRow.Item("Name") = TextBox1.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("Address1") = TextBox2.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("Address2") = TextBox3.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("Town") = TextBox4.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("County") = TextBox5.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("Country") = TextBox6.Text
        dSet_NewRow.Item("PostCode") = TextBox7.Text
        dSet.Tables("Table").Rows.Add(dSet_NewRow)
        da.Update(dSet, "Table")
        dSet.Tables.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Connecting to database

```
Sub Connect()
    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = connString
        conn.Open()
        'If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'MsgBox("open")
        'End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Putting information in a dataset

```
Sub getTable()
    Try
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
        da.Fill(dSet, "Table")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

does anyone know how to use a loop to dynamically assign input using the controls without having to name the textbox1, textbox2......

Answer (score 0):

Your methods for reuse would have the variables supplied to them.

```
Public Shared Sub LoadSomeData(name As String, addr1 As String, addr2 As String, town As String, county As String, country As String, pc As String)
 Try
    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim dSet_NewRow As DataRow
    dSet_NewRow = dSet.Tables("Table").NewRow
    dSet_NewRow.Item("Name") = name
    dSet_NewRow.Item("Address1") = addr1
    dSet_NewRow.Item("Address2") = addr2
    dSet_NewRow.Item("Town") = town
    dSet_NewRow.Item("County") = county
    dSet_NewRow.Item("Country") = country
    dSet_NewRow.Item("PostCode") = pc
    dSet.Tables("Table").Rows.Add(dSet_NewRow)
    da.Update(dSet, "Table")
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
LoadSomeData(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, textbox4.Text, textbox5.Text, textbox6.Text, textbox7.Text)
```

Though I hope you get around to naming the Textboxes with a name that has some meaning - tbName, tbAddress, etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I do get what you are saying but i dont get how to assign data to these variables dynamically. And what would I do if I want to use the same sub on a different form with different controls using different field names for the table I am writing to ?

Comment: `name` would be a variable.  it can come from `Form1.txtCustName` or `Form13.txtSomeOtehrName`.  youd supply the value when you call the sub